# Navigation icons are disappearing when accessing stack pages in react native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am using react navigation (https://reactnavigation.org/) to display icons for the bottom navigation tabs. Icons are displaying fine, however, when I enter into pages in the stack, the icons disappear.

I can get the icons to show by referring to the icon image on each page individually, but I am wondering if there is a better way to do this. Thanks.

```
    static navigationOptions = {
    tabBarIcon: () => (
      <Image
        source={require('../../assets/profile.png')}
        style={styles.icon}
      />
      )
    }
```

Comment: Were you able to figure anything out? Stuck on the same issue. I don't want to manually set tab icons for each screen since some screens can be accessed by multiple tabs and I'd want the tab icon from where it came from to be shown.

Comment: any update on this ?? How did you make it back appear

Answer (score -1):

In my case my cell phone time was not correct. As soon as I made my cell phone same as my computer time my issue was fixed.